# ArrayList.contains() return false on equals strings sometimes

Tags: java, collections

I have some trouble with my 'cache' list:

```
private static List<String> urlsCacheList = new ArrayList<String>();
...
 private static void parseUrlsToQueue(Content content){
        String str = content.toString();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(CSS_JS_PATTERN);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            String link = m.group();
            if(link.equals("http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css")){
                LOG.warn("******************cache CONTAINS STRING http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css " + urlsCacheList.contains(link) + " ;" + link +";" );
            }

            if(!urlsCacheList.contains(link)){
                urlsCacheList.add(link);
                queue.add(link);
            }
        }
    }
```

So after some iterations `urlsCacheList.contains(link)` return false on the equals links, and

```
LOG.warn("******************cache CONTAINS STRING http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css " + urlsCacheList.contains(link) + " ;" + link +";" );
```

prints: 
`cache CONTAINS STRING http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css false ;http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css;`

But its mostly return true on the same strings, each 30 or 40 iterations its returns false;

**UPDATE1:**
Sorry guys by its seems to me that problem in another place, I call parseUrls() method from Fetcher.class like that:

```
..
ContentParser.parseUrlsToQueue(content);
..
```

so after some iterations  my urlsCacheList  just re-init to null , becaus of own class re-creation;

Comment: Side note: consider to use a Set instead of a List for your cache for a faster look-up.

Comment: thx, for hint, I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the string object hash id's for the strings which fails the contains check. I think it might be because a new String object is created for few Strings and due to this its behaving like this.

One solution is to call String.intern() method to solve this problem.

Comment: Please post questions like this as comments not as answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but IMO this does provide the answer to the above question. If the poster use String.intern() it will resolve the issue.